# JOIN on three tables is not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have these three tables, `user`, `categories` and `files`

In `users`, table I have a column `user_id`

[image]

And I have this query that shows all Categories.

```
SELECT
    `categories`.`category_id`, `categories`.`timestamp`,`categories`.`name`,       
    LEFT(`categories`.`description`, 50) as `description`,
    COUNT(`files`.`file_id`) as `file_count`
FROM `categories`
LEFT JOIN `files`
    ON `categories`.`category_id` = `files`.`category_id`
GROUP BY `categories`.`category_id`
```

What I want to do is that to show only categories which are created by specific user.
Adding a `WHERE user.user_id = categories.category_id` gives

> Unknown column users.user_id

Comment: The only part you have omitted is the part which matters... you want to type `user.user_id`, but SQL is reporting you gave it an "s" with `users.user_id`.  Edit: Actually, you're crossing the plural usage in your writeup, so not 100% certain... I'd check there, though (perhaps in the reverse).

Comment: `WHERE categories.user_id = 2` would show you categories created by user_id 2

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not joining `users` table anywhere (also, you have a typo in your WHERE statement: `user.user_id`, should be `users.user_id`).

So, I guess you want to add something like (in your FROM statement):

`categories INNER JOIN users ON categories.user_id = users.user_id`

And the filter by a `user_id` you like (using a where statement).

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As you are not taking any extra information from user table so no need to join user table here. Below query should give you desired results.

```
SELECT
    `categories`.`category_id`, `categories`.`timestamp`,`categories`.`name`,       
    LEFT(`categories`.`description`, 50) as `description`,
    COUNT(`files`.`file_id`) as `file_count`
FROM `categories`
LEFT JOIN `files`
    ON `categories`.`category_id` = `files`.`category_id`
where `categories`.`user_id` = 2
GROUP BY `categories`.`category_id`;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to include some information from users table you definitely should join on users table also. Or maybe if you want to count all categories created by a specific user. Otherwise there is no purpose to do `WHERE user.user_id = categories.category_id`.

If this is not the case filter by `categories.category_id`.